# Is a locally compact Hausdorff quotient of a locally compact $\sigma$-compact first countable Hausdorff space always first countable?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, first-countable

Let $Y$ be a locally compact, $\sigma$-compact, first countable Hausdorff space
and $q: Y\to X$ a quotient map with $X$ Hausdorff. Suppose that $X$ is locally compact. Is $X$ first countable?

I have spent a while hunting the literature for an answer but have not been able to find one. It works the other way: if $X$ is first countable then $X$ is locally compact, but what about this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.  Let $Y=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with the order topology of the lexicographic order (so $Y$ is first countable, compact, and Hausdorff).  Let $X$ be the quotient of $Y$ that identifies $[0,1]\times\{0,1\}$ to a single point.  This is a closed subset of $Y$, so the quotient is still compact Hausdorff.  However, $X$ is not first-countable: it is the one-point compactification of a disjoint union of uncountably many copies of $(0,1)$ (the image of $[0,1]\times(0,1)\subset X$, which has the product topology where the first coordinate is discrete and the second has the usual topology), which is not first-countable at the point at infinity.

Comment: Very good! Many thanks.

Comment: If this quotient (which is sequential) would be Fréchet-Urysohn, it would be a counterexample to the follow-up question too. But I think that $q$ is hereditarily quotient, so in this form it won't work..